# to break the tree in even number of nodes

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

You are given a tree (a simple connected graph with no cycles).

Find the maximum number of edges you can remove from the tree to get a forest such that each connected component of the forest contains an even number of nodes.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/even-tree/problem

In the above link the test cases are given. For sampple input 1, I am getting  0 as output instead of expected value 2.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int ans = 0;
int v, e;
int visited[201];
int gph[201][201];

int dfs(int i) {
    int num_nodes;
    int num_vertex = 0;
    visited[i] = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= v; j++) {
        if (visited[i] == 0 && gph[i][j] == 1) {
            num_nodes = dfs(j);
            if (num_nodes % 2 == 0)
                ans++;
            else
                num_vertex += num_nodes;
        }
    }
    return num_vertex + 1;
}

int main() {
    scanf("%d %d", &v, &e); // vertices and edges
    int u, v;
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &u, &v); //edges of undirected graph
        gph[u][v] = 1;
        gph[v][u] = 1;
    }
    dfs(1);
    printf("%d", ans);
}
```

> Test case:
>
> 10 9
> 2 1
> 3 1
> 4 3
> 5 2
> 6 1
> 7 2
> 8 6
> 9 8
> 10 8

- Expected output: **2**
- Actual output: **0**

Comment: Please adhere to the posting guidelines: supply the problem test case in your posting.  The link you gave does not permit general access; don't expect people to create an account specifically to diagnose your problem.  Just hard-code the example into your code -- reading input shouldn't be part of the problem, so it shouldn't be in this posting.

Comment: done boss @Prune

Comment: Not done, replace the `scanf()` calls. The goal should be to provide a [mcve]. BTW: Do some research why using global variables is a bad idea, that may well cause your problems. Also, learn how to use a debugger to step through code.

Comment: When your program is producing incorrect output, the correct thing to do is to use a debugger and trace through its execution.  You may also wish to work through it on paper.  You could add statements to display intermediate values during execution to test or debunk assumptions you're making.  The time to post a question on Stack Overflow is _after_ you have done all the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// ans is total number of edges removed and al is adjacency list of the tree.
int dfs(int node) 
{
    visit[node]=true;
    int num_vertex=0;
    for(int i=0;i<al[node].size();i++)
    {
        if(!visit[al[node][i]])
        {
            int num_nodes=dfs(al[node][i]);
            if(num_nodes%2==0)
                ans++;
            else
                num_vertex+=num_nodes;
        }
    }
    return num_vertex+1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo. The condition expression in `if` clause

```
if (visited[i] == 0 && gph[i][j] == 1)
```

should be

```
if (visited[j] == 0 && gph[i][j] == 1)
```

BTW, the constraints in hackrank question is `2 <= n <= 100`, so you definitely don't need a fixed array of size 201.